# c11 flag is ignored in the make file

Tags: makefile, compilation

I try to compile my code with c11 mode.
Here is my make file:

```
obj-m := message_slot.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
CFLAGS=-g -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules


clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

for some reason during compilation, the compiler still try to compile the code with c90. Does anyone understand why?

```
/home/eran/CLionProjects/tau_os_ex3/message_slot.c:29:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
```

Comment: `c++11` chooses the C++ 11 standard.  If you want to use the C 11 standard, choose `c11`.  And, as John says, use the `CFLAGS` variable (for C compilers) not the `CXXFLAGS` variable (for C++ compilers)

Comment: This has nothing to do with C11 itself, but with your build system and your configuration of make. This depends on a lot of things, your OS, your compiler, ... You should also provide more information, e.g the compilation line that your make has really chosen to execute.

Answer (score 1):

`CXXFLAGS` conveys build flags for C++, but the error message indicates that you are trying to build a C source.  C compiler flags go in `CFLAGS`.

Comment: I followed your instructions (edited the post) no change.